# What can I use as a drainage solution against foundation of timber frame house?

Tags: drainage

We live in an old house (1400s) with a timber frame. At some point, it looks like somebody poured thick concrete from the patio right up to the foundation which has left a concrete trench against the horizontal timber frame at the base of the building.

We tried to have a French drain installed but the concrete managed to break all of the builder's drill equipment so they never came back. They thought a digger would cause too many vibrations and wouldn't be safe.

Given we can't remove the concrete, I'm not sure if there's any other solutions?

I don't know whether leaving it exposed (as it is now) is better as it lets the sun dry it out - or whether we should fill it with gravel.

The patio does tend to flow away from the house but I don't know if the rot to the beams is recent (decades wise) from sitting water or potentially from hundreds of years and isn't such a problem[image: picture of foundation]

Does anybody have any thoughts about what we could do?

Note: we live in England, lots of rain...

[image: different angle]
[image: another angle]

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: Simple, consider the cost of replacing the wood frame compared to the cost of dealing with the concrete.

Comment: I'm not sure how thick the concrete is but we've struggled to get anyone to do the job. The builder's that tried managed to break all their equipment. Our preference was definitely to get it dug out and to install a French drain but it doesn't seem like it's an option

Comment: Rock might beat scissors, but there are other steel tools that will beat rock.  If that stuff is stronger than a jack hammer had harder than quick-cut saw  you might need to get an excavator with a rock breaker.

Comment: A wet diamond saw should be able to cut it. Once cut sufficiently it's easy to break up without a lot of vibration, if that's a concern. If they broke all their equipment they didn't know what they were doing and brought the wrong equipment, IMHO.